# Nomenclature for a unital magma together with a monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, monoid, magma

Is there some established name/nomenclature for structures $\mathfrak{A} = (A,\, {\oplus},\, {\odot})$, where

- $(A,\, {\oplus})$ forms a (commutative) unital magma (in particular not associative!),
- $(A,\, {\odot})$ forms a (commutative) monoid, and
- $\odot$ distributes over $\oplus$ ?

I am looking for something like "$\mathfrak{A}$ is a skew field" or similar.

Comment: By the distributive property, $(a \oplus b) \odot (c \oplus d)=[(a \odot c) \oplus (a \odot d)] \oplus [(b \odot c) \oplus (b \odot d)]=[(a \odot c) \oplus (b \odot c)] \oplus [(a \odot d) \oplus (b \odot d)]$.

Comment: Meaning what regarding nomenclature?